# ES6 arrow functions and array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am trying to understand some shorthand ways of writing ES6.
What I cannot fully understand in the example below is the last shorthand "({length})" - I comprehend that it does work, and that it gets the length property of the array, but not why. How could this syntax be applied in another scenario, not involving arrays?

```
//Declare array
var materials = [
  'Hydrogen',
  'Helium',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

//Long version - ok
materials.map(function(material) { 
  return material.length; 
});

//Arrow function - ok
materials.map((material) => {
  return material.length;
});

//Shorthand arrow function - ok
materials.map(str => str.length);

//What? :)
materials.map( ({length}) => length );
```

The example above is from the mozilla documentation of arrow functions.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `length` is a property of strings, and can be [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) and returned in the map.

It's mostly the same as:

```
materials.map((str) => {
  const {length} = str;
  return length;
});
```